# vocabulary question: manners vs. mannerisms

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> "It is a good mannerism to reply for a message".

Is this sentence right? If so then why? Which one should be used in the above line — "good mannerism" or "good manners"?

Answer (score 11):

The sentence you're looking for is:

> It is good manners to reply to a message.

The phrase is "reply to" and not "reply for", but I guess your confusion is between the word "manners" and the word "mannerisms". They mean different things:

- *manners* (or *good manners*, always plural) refers to *etiquette*, things that are considered polite, or expected in society. (You already know this meaning.) Example: "It is good manners to reply to a message."
- *mannerisms* are idiosyncrasies or other peculiar behaviour specific to a person, his/her *style* of doing things, speaking, etc. Example: "[Rajinikanth](http://www.slate.com/id/2267820/pagenum/all/) is a star mostly for his mannerisms."

Comment: +1 for the answer. As a side note, I know more than a few people who will be likely to try and lynch you for your 2nd example :-) :-)

Comment: This answer is correct, but I would prefer *"It is polite to reply to a message."* Seems more direct and less clunky.